# Trying to implement an AlphaVideo Shader for AFrame. Issues with material.needsUpdate

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to create a video with alpha Shader, which I had working in three.js, but I'm having trouble getting it translated to AFrame.  What I'm seeing is that the shader doesn't apply correctly at first and if I apply a standard shader then reselect the alphaMatte shader, it will show a frame of the video but not the video playing.  Where would I set material.needsUpdate or how do I get my shader initialized correctly at start?

Here is the shader code for reference:

```
AFRAME.registerShader('alphamatte', {
      schema: {
        src: {type: 'map'},
        transparent: {default: true}
      },

      vertexShader: [
        'varying vec2 vUv;',
        'varying float texU;',
        'void main()',
        '{',
        'vUv = uv;',
        'vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
        'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;',
        '}'
      ].join('\n'),

      fragmentShader: [
        'uniform sampler2D texture;',
        'uniform vec3 color;',
        'varying vec2 vUv;',
        'void main()',
        '{',
        'vec2 texcoord = vec2(0.49, 0.0);',
        'vec2 halfTex = vec2(0.5, 1.0);',
        'vec3 tColor = texture2D( texture, ( vUv * halfTex ) ).rgb;',
        'vec3 aColor = texture2D( texture, ( (vUv * halfTex ) + texcoord ) ).rgb;',
        'float a = aColor.g;',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(tColor, a);',
        '}'
      ].join('\n')
    })


<!doctype html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <title>alphaMatte</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="alphamatteShader.js"></script>

 <body style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7)">
    <a-scene>
        <a-assets>
          <video id="alphavideo" src="gangnam.mp4" loop autoplay muted />
        </a-assets>
        <a-entity id="vidCube" material="shader: alphamatte; src: #alphavideo" geometry="primitive: box" position="0 0.0 -4.0"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>

</html>
```

When I run the html with the shader applied to the cube.. it comes up invisible. If I change the shader to standard in the editor then it shows moving video. If I reapply the alphamatte shader it shows a frame of video with alpha knocked out, but the video doesn't play.. I'm guessing that I need to update the texture on the tick? But where?

Answer (score 0):

so I have it working after some exploration of my original threejs source and realizing I should use the THREE.ShaderMaterial referenced here.. threejs.org/docs/api/materials/ShaderMaterial.html

Here's the working code.

```
AFRAME.registerShader('alphamatte', {
      schema: {
        src: {type: 'map', is: 'uniform'},
        transparent: {default: true, is: 'uniform'}
      },
      init: function (data) {
        var videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(data.src);
            videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

        this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        uniforms: {
            texture: {
                type: "t",
                value: videoTexture
            }
        },
        vertexShader: this.vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: this.fragmentShader });
      },

      update: function (data) {
        this.material.src = data.src;
        this.material.transparent = data.transparent;
      },

      vertexShader: [
        'varying vec2 vUv;',
        'varying float texU;',
        'void main()',
        '{',
        'vUv = uv;',
        'vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
        'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;',
        '}'
      ].join('\n'),

      fragmentShader: [
        'uniform sampler2D texture;',
        'uniform vec3 color;',
        'varying vec2 vUv;',
        'void main()',
        '{',
        'vec2 texcoord = vec2(0.49, 0.0);',
        'vec2 halfTex = vec2(0.5, 1.0);',
        'vec3 tColor = texture2D( texture, ( vUv * halfTex ) ).rgb;',
        'vec3 aColor = texture2D( texture, ( (vUv * halfTex ) + texcoord ) ).rgb;',
        'float a = aColor.g;',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(tColor, a);',
        '}'
      ].join('\n')
    })
```

However, now I get some WebGL errors saying. 
"Error: WebGL: texImage2D: Failed to hit GPU-copy fast-path. Falling back to CPU upload. aframe.min.js:107:826 
Error: WebGL: texImage2D: Conversion requires pixel reformatting. aframe.min.js:107:826